# Render meshlab scene to image

Tags: meshlab

Is it possible to render a meshlab scene to an image, like taking a screenshot?  I ultimately want to do this programmatically.

Specifically I'm after something that allows it to be done via MeshlabServer's API.

Comment: this is apparently possible but seems like a hassle. probably the advice to go w/ blender is good advice. https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/119

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible and it is not planned to do that by the moment.
The reason is that meshlab is focused on polygon mesh processing, not in rendering. For the case of meshlabserver, it is even more focused in processing (that why its input are scripts) and even less focused in rendering (that why it is a console application that do not create a render context).

If you are planning to render a lot of 3D files, I would suggest to use blender instead. A small python script running in the interpreter bundled with blender can do the work you have in mind.